# How to view diff of a file in github?

Tags: git, github

I saw the following https://help.github.com/articles/comparing-commits-across-time/

It says "To get to the compare view, append /compare to your repository's path."

but where is the repository's path? if I add it to the url of the page then it simply goes to 404 page not found.

Comment: Works fine for me: https://github.com/github/linguist/compare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repository path always looks like this:
https://github.com/OWNERNAME/REPONAME

Just add
/compare
to this path.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to diff individual files

Comment: @Allahjane When you select a file and click on the **History** button you get the commit history of the file. There you can select a commit (by clicking on the commit message) and get all the changes made in this commit.

Answer (score 0):

Your git path is always depends on your username. Different types of website give git repository service such as github,gitlab, bitbucket etc. If you create an account there then your username will be like below.

suppose, your username for github is **someone** . So your profile will be 
**https://github.com/someone

https://gitlab.com/someone

https://bitbucket.com/someone**

If you make repository in your profile then it will be like below. Suppose, you have made a repository called **something** . Then your repository will be 

**https://github.com/someone/something

https://gitlab.com/someone/something

https://bitbucket.com/someone/something**

Hope that, you have got idea about git path in the repository